# Histogram with density curves of other data

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to recreate [image: this histogram] but I have trouble to fit the density curves to the plot.

MWE ( of what I achieved so far. Data in the tibble are just sample data) :

```
tibble(home = sample(1:10,90, replace = T), away = sample(1:10,90, replace = T)) %>% 
gather(key=Type, value=Value) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Value,fill=Type)) + 
geom_histogram(position="dodge")
```

UPDATE after answer by @Kota Mori

I adjusted the answer given by Kota Mori to get the following which results in an error. Before I start lets have a look at the datasets I want to use for the graph :

```
#Both Goals variables of this dataframe should be used for the histogram
actual
# A tibble: 90 x 7
   season matchday club_name_home      club_name_away        goals_team_home goals_team_away sumgoals
    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>               <chr>                           <dbl>           <dbl>    <dbl>
 1   1819       21 ETuS Haltern        TuS 05 Sinsen II                    2               2        4
 2   1819       21 VfL Ramsdorf        Westfalia Gemen II                  2               0        2
 3   1819       21 FC RW Dorsten       SV Altendorf-Ulfkotte               8               4       12
 4   1819       21 SuS Hervest-Dorsten 1. SC BW Wulfen                     0               0        0
 5   1819       21 SV Lembeck          SC Reken II                         1               1        2
 6   1819       21 RC Borken-Hoxfeld   TSV Raesfeld                        3               1        4
 7   1819       21 TuS Velen           Fenerbahce I. Marl                  5               2        7
 8   1819       21 BVH Dorsten         SC Marl-Hamm                        2               0        2
 9   1819       21 1. SC BW Wulfen     FC RW Dorsten                       3               0        3
10   1819       21 BVH Dorsten         SV Altendorf-Ulfkotte               2               0        2
# ... with 80 more rows


#Both Goals variables of this dataframe should be used for the density lines
poisson
# A tibble: 90 x 6
   season matchday club_name_home      club_name_away        Goals_team_home Goals_team_away
    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>               <chr>                           <dbl>           <dbl>
 1   1819       21 ETuS Haltern        TuS 05 Sinsen II                    2               2
 2   1819       21 VfL Ramsdorf        Westfalia Gemen II                  3               0
 3   1819       21 FC RW Dorsten       SV Altendorf-Ulfkotte               2               0
 4   1819       21 SuS Hervest-Dorsten 1. SC BW Wulfen                     0               4
 5   1819       21 SV Lembeck          SC Reken II                         2               1
 6   1819       21 RC Borken-Hoxfeld   TSV Raesfeld                        2               1
 7   1819       21 TuS Velen           Fenerbahce I. Marl                  2               1
 8   1819       21 BVH Dorsten         SC Marl-Hamm                        3               1
 9   1819       21 1. SC BW Wulfen     FC RW Dorsten                       2               0
10   1819       21 BVH Dorsten         SV Altendorf-Ulfkotte               2               1
# ... with 80 more rows
```

So I adjusted the answer by Kota Mori to end up with the following code :

```
simyears = 1819
actual <- read_rds(here::here(paste0("/data/database_match_results_",sim_years,".rds")))%>%
    filter(between(matchday, 21, max(database_season$matchday))) 
  poisson <- missinggames 
  
    
  data <- rbind(data.frame(type="home", value=actual$goals_team_home, stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
                data.frame(type="away", value=actual$goals_team_home, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
  
  estimate <- group_by(poisson %>% select(Goals_team_home,Goals_team_away), type) %>% summarize(mu=mean(value))
  dens <- expand.grid(value=0:max(data$value), type=c("away", "home"),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
    inner_join(estimate) %>%
    mutate(density=dpois(value, mu))
  prop <- group_by(data, type, value) %>% summarize(count=n()) %>%
    group_by(type) %>% mutate(prop=count/sum(count)) 
  tmp_actual <- left_join(dens, prop) %>% replace_na(list(prop=0, count=0))
  

  
    ggplot(tmp_actual, aes(x=value, weight=prop, fill=type)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge") +
    geom_line(aes(value, density, color=type, weight=NULL))
```

Which results in the following error : 'Error: Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`.'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to calculate the poisson parameters on your own, which turns out to be as easy as calculating the sample mean for each type.
The following code generates a graph similar to the example.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- rbind(data.frame(type="home", value=rpois(90, 2.5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
              data.frame(type="away", value=rpois(90, 1.5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

estimate <- group_by(data, type) %>% summarize(mu=mean(value))
dens <- expand.grid(value=0:max(data$value), type=c("away", "home"),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
  inner_join(estimate) %>%
  mutate(density=dpois(value, mu))
prop <- group_by(data, type, value) %>% summarize(count=n()) %>%
  group_by(type) %>% mutate(prop=count/sum(count)) 
tmp <- left_join(dens, prop) %>% replace_na(list(prop=0, count=0))

ggplot(tmp, aes(x=value, weight=prop, fill=type)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge") +
  geom_line(aes(value, density, color=type, weight=NULL))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far. Just to clarify what I wanted and what you did. 

I have two datasets. One contains the actual goals distribution of a soccer league and  the other one the predicted  goals distribution given by a poisson model. What I want is to create a histogram of the actual goals distribution and add density lines of the predicted distribution. Did you do the same in your answer? Because I think you just added a density line of the same distribution given in the histogram but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, the histogram of data and the line from the poisson distribution using the estimated parameter.  In the code, the parameter has been estimated in `estimate <- ...` by computing the mean by the type (which is the maximum likelihood estimate for the poisson distribution).  If you have obtained the estimate elsewhere, you can replace the `estimate` data frame by your own parameter estimates.

Comment: I get an error that the mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`. I will update the OP to clarify things further.